# How to import a specific font from your computer to R

Tags: r

I plotted points on a map, and now I want to add a title and change the font to be a specific font downloaded on my computer called DIN Next LT Pro.

I noticed that font portion of the text function takes a number, and I have experimented with changing the number, but I don't have a way of knowing which font is which, and if the one I want is even an option (I assume it is not). I read something about the pdf function that allows you to import certain fonts, but I am not sure how this works and if you still need to somehow import the font.

```
map <-
  points(x=from$lon, y=from$lat, pch=19, cex=from$peso_neto/3000000000, col="yellow green")
  text(x=50, y=75, labels= "Las exportaciones de la provincia de 
Buenos Aires al mundo", col="grey80", font = 2)
```

Comment: See `?par`, section `Graphical Parameters`, the `font` and `family` arguments.

Comment: Try this library: https://github.com/wch/extrafont

Comment: I'd recommend [`showtext`](https://github.com/yixuan/showtext) over `extrafont`, since it's much more robust, has fewer restrictions on font types and matching to graphics devices, and is in active development. `extrafont` hasn't had a github commit since 2014